# union infinite loop scala

Tags: scala, recursion, union

I am learning scala and by attending the Odersky course online. In the third assignment there is an exercise where you have to work with a tweet set. One of the operations a tweet set should support is `union`. That is, a union between two sets is a new set containing tweets from both sets.

I implemented this operations as follows:

```
abstract class TweetSet {
   def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet
   def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet
}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
 def union(that:TweetSet): TweetSet = that
 def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = new NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
     if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
     else if (x.text > elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
     else this
   }

   def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    (left union (right union that)) incl elem //:: 1 Okay
   // ((right union left) union that) incl elem //:: 2 Infinite loop
}
```

I can't understand why the order used to merge sets matters. This really doesn't make any sense to me. The first line in my code works properly, whereas the second line causes an infinite loop. The order of the operands of an union should not matter, and I should get the same result independently from which line I decide to use.

The order I use is the order used by Odersky in its lecture online so I can't understand why it is causing an infinite loop in certain cases.

I think there is a bug in my code, but I can't find it. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What are `left` and `right`? It seems like there are pieces missing.

Comment: @m-z Thank you. I didn't properly copy the constructor. I updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong; can you post the test code you're using which produces an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not infinite loop. It's finite loop, but second variant involves much more operations.

Assuming

```
case class Tweet(text: String)
```

We could define simple

```
var unionsCalled = 0
```

and add line

```
unionsCalled += 1
```

to both `Empty` and `NonEmpty`s union implementations

then running lines

```
(1 to 30).view map (_.toString) map Tweet map (new NonEmpty(_, new Empty, new Empty)) reduce (_ union _)
println(unionsCalled)
```

gives us final `unionsCalled` value of `899` for first implementation variant and `149489` for second

This is happening because of inbalanced trees.
In worst case your alorigthm to `union` single item and `n` item sets should create new set of `n - 1` element then include `elem` and then `that.elem`. Which could degrade to `2^(n/2)` sometimes.

To accurately implement efficient set you should search links in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

I dare myself to reimplement your task using simple [randomized search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) which is simplest to code

```
import scala.util.Random

case class Tweet(text: String)

abstract class TweetSet {
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet
  def rankInsert(tweet: Tweet, rank: Int): TweetSet
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = rankInsert(tweet, Random.nextInt())
  def toList: List[Tweet]
  def depth: Int
}

case object Empty extends TweetSet {
  def depth = 0
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that
  def rankInsert(tweet: Tweet, rank: Int) = NonEmpty(tweet, Empty, Empty, rank)
  def toList = List()
}

case class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, 
                    left: TweetSet, 
                    right: TweetSet, 
                    rank: Int) extends TweetSet {
  lazy val depth = (left.depth max right.depth) + 1
  def attachToParent(tweet: Tweet, rank: Int) = if (tweet.text < elem.text)
    NonEmpty(tweet, Empty, this, rank)
  else NonEmpty(tweet, this, Empty, rank)

  def rankInsert(tweet: Tweet, rank: Int) =
    if (tweet.text == elem.text) this
    else if (rank > this.rank) attachToParent(tweet, rank)
    else if (tweet.text < elem.text) copy(left = left.rankInsert(tweet, rank))
    else copy(right = right.rankInsert(tweet, rank))

  def toList = left.toList ++ (elem :: right.toList)
  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = if (depth > that.depth) that.union(this)
  else (that /: toList)(_ incl _ )
}

object TweetSet {
  def empty: TweetSet = Empty
  def apply(tweets: Tweet*) = (empty /:  tweets)( _ incl _ )
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you more up-votes and I encourage anyone  reading this answer to do so. Thank you very much for your help. I have one more question, why my implementation degenerates to 2^(n/2)? in the worst case shouldn't degenerate to a list? Therefore a complexity of n?

Comment: @GiuseppePes Thank you!  I thought about of your question a lot, but did not achieve to derive some formula or law describing complexity growth. [Here my work on it](https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/41c0cff2313bd92cc238). It involves some scalaz if you comfortable with it.